# Python tabula- cannot import name wrapper

Tags: python

I am facing an issue in importing the wrapper from tabula

Line throwing error:

```
from tabula import wrapper
```

I am using Python 3.4

Error -  "cannot import name wrapper"

Comment: What error is it throwing

Comment: nehaj, my friend - we need a bit more information. For example, what does the error say?

Comment: @nehaj what is the error that you are getting.?

Comment: Error - cannot import name wrapper

Comment: @SreeramTP can you help please?

Comment: have you installed tabula  properly.? check with doing `import tabula`. If it throws any error it is not properly installed

Comment: yeah it is imported properly, doesn't throw any error in import tabula. but when i import wrapper it throws an error

Comment: @nehaj do you have another file called tabula.py in the same directory?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using the **tabula python wrapper**. I think you installed the wrong pip package for tabula which is causing it to not find the wrapper module. (Maybe `pip install tabula`)

Try:

```
pip install tabula-py
```

or depending on your pip configuration:

```
pip3 install tabula-py
```

[The link to the pip package.](https://pypi.org/project/tabula-py/1.3.0/)

Comment: I like cabbage, do you?